# Check if all input fields within specific div is filled and echo text js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I have 2 divs that contain multiple input fields and I am trying to check if they are filled and if so to print specific text in another div.

For whatever reason, NOTHING I've tried has made it work, and I've searched forever for an answer. This is the code I currently have --

```
// if for sale
var fsdiv = $("div#lp-fs-costs");

fsdiv2 = fsdiv.find("input[type=text]");

//if (fsdiv2.trim().length) 

var value = $.trim($("fdiv2").val());

if(value.length>0) {

$('#ls-anc-info').append('<br /> You added cost details.' );
} else {
$('#ls-anc-info').append('<br /> You have not added any cost details.' );
}


// if for rent
var frdiv = $("div#lp-fr-costs");

if($(frdiv.find("input[type=text]")).length > 0) {

$('#ls-anc-info').append('<br /> You added cost details.' );
} else {
$('#ls-anc-info').append('<br /> You have not added any cost details.' );
}
```

Code I was trying before --

```
// If for sale
//var fsdiv = $("#lp-fs-costs");
//var inputs = fsdiv.find("input");

var inputs2 = document.getElementById('lp-fs-costs').getElementsByTagName('input');

if($(inputs2).val().length > 0) {

$('#ls-anc-info').append('<br /> You added cost details.' );
} else {
$('#ls-anc-info').append('<br /> You have not added any cost details.' );
}


// If for rent
//if ( ($("label[for=for-rent]").hasClass("active")) && ($("#for-rent:checked")) ) {
//var frdiv = $("#lp-fr-costs");

if($("#lp-fr-costs :input").val().length > 0) {

$('#ls-anc-info').append('<br /> You added cost details.' );
} else {
$('#ls-anc-info').append('<br / >You have not added any cost details.' );
}

//}
```

**UPDATE**

My html code is quite extensive, it's a multi-step form. The relevant part to my question though is --

```
<div class="aic-section">

<!-- FIELDS FOR RENT ALL IN COSTS -->
<div id="lp-fr-costs" class="lp-fr-divs" style="display: block;">

<!-- FR CABLE -->
<div class="subins2">
<div class="sublabel-aic">CABLE/WIFI</div>
<div class="aic-lp">
<input name="tco_tvnet" value="" type="text" class="form-control money" placeholder="$">
</div>
</div>

<!-- FR UTILITIES -->
<div class="subins2">
<div class="sublabel-aic">UTILITIES</div>
<div class="aic-lp">
<input name="tco_elec" value="" type="text" class="form-control money" placeholder="$">
</div>
</div>

<!-- MORE INPUT FIELDS ETC. -->

</div>
<!-- END FIELDS FOR RENT ALL IN COSTS -->

<!-- FIELDS FOR SALE ALL IN COSTS -->
<div id="lp-fs-costs" class="lp-fs-divs" style="display: none;">

<!-- FS HOA -->
<div class="subins2">
<div class="sublabel-aic">Common Charges/HOA</div>
<div class="aic-lp">
<input name="tco_hoa" value="" type="text" class="form-control money" placeholder="$" disabled="">
</div>
</div>

<!-- FS TAXES -->                                           
<div class="subins2">
<div class="sublabel-aic">Taxes (Monthly)</div>
<div class="aic-lp">
<input name="tco_tax" value="" type="text" class="form-control money" placeholder="$" disabled="">
</div>
</div>

<!-- MORE INPUT FIELDS ETC. -->

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please share your html.

Comment: Can you share your entire code including the html structure?

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt I updated it

Comment: @Swamy I updated it

Comment: How you want to check it...on button click or on page load??

Comment: I have on my "next" button a onclick calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to iterate over all the `input` field in the div to check whether they are empty or not.

```
var $empties = $("div#lp-fs-costs input[type='text']").filter(function() {
   return !this.value.trim()
});
if ($empties.length) {
   $('#ls-anc-info').empty();
   $('#ls-anc-info').append('<br /> You have not added cost details.' );
} else {
  $('#ls-anc-info').empty();
  $('#ls-anc-info').append('<br /> You added cost details.' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery, you can use this simple trick

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var c = $("div#lp-fs-costs input[type='text']").filter(function() { return this.value == ""; }).length;
  if (c > 0) {
      console.log('there is ' + c + ' empty input');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lp-fs-costs">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<button>check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to make two functions for both `rent` and `sale` like 
**`checksale()`** and **`checkrent()`** and then trigger them on button click or on load. I have made a snippet for you on button click.

If you want trigger them on load just call the functions inside **`document.ready`** like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  checksale();
  checkrent();
});
```

```js
function checksale() {
  var inputLength = $("div#lp-fs-costs input[type=text]").length;
  var emptyLength = $("div#lp-fs-costs input[type=text]").filter(function() {
    return this.value == ""
  }).length;
  if (emptyLength > 0) {
    $('#ls-anc-info').html('<p style="color:red;">You have not added some/any cost details.</p>');
  } else {
    $('#ls-anc-info').html('<p style="color:green;">You have added all cost details.</p>');
  }
}

function checkrent() {
  var inputLength = $("div#lp-fr-costs input[type=text]").length;
  var emptyLength = $("div#lp-fr-costs input[type=text]").filter(function() {
    return this.value == ""
  }).length;
  if (emptyLength > 0) {
    $('#lr-anc-info').html('<p style="color:red;">You have not added some/any cost details.</p>');
  } else {
    $('#lr-anc-info').html('<p style="color:green;">You have added all cost details.</p>');
  }
}

$('#checksale').on('click', function() {
  checksale();
})

$('#checkrent').on('click', function() {
  checkrent();
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.sublabel-aic,
.aic-lp {
  display: inline-block;
}

#lp-fr-costs,
#lp-fs-costs {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

#checkrent,
#checksale {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aic-section">
  <!-- FIELDS FOR RENT ALL IN COSTS -->
  <div id="lp-fr-costs" class="lp-fr-divs" style="display: block;">
    <!-- FR CABLE -->
    <div class="subins2">
      <div class="sublabel-aic">CABLE/WIFI</div>
      <div class="aic-lp">
        <input name="tco_tvnet" value="" type="text" class="form-control money" placeholder="$">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- FR UTILITIES -->
    <div class="subins2">
      <div class="sublabel-aic">UTILITIES</div>
      <div class="aic-lp">
        <input name="tco_elec" value="" type="text" class="form-control money" placeholder="$">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MORE INPUT FIELDS ETC. -->
    <button id="checkrent">Check Rent</button>
  </div>
  <!-- END FIELDS FOR RENT ALL IN COSTS -->
  <div id="lr-anc-info"></div>
  <!-- FIELDS FOR SALE ALL IN COSTS -->
  <div id="lp-fs-costs" class="lp-fs-divs" style="display: ;">
    <!-- FS HOA -->
    <div class="subins2">
      <div class="sublabel-aic">Common Charges/HOA</div>
      <div class="aic-lp">
        <input name="tco_hoa" value="" type="text" class="form-control money" placeholder="$">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- FS TAXES -->
    <div class="subins2">
      <div class="sublabel-aic">Taxes (Monthly)</div>
      <div class="aic-lp">
        <input name="tco_tax" value="" type="text" class="form-control money" placeholder="$">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MORE INPUT FIELDS ETC. -->
    <button id="checksale">Check Sale</button>
  </div>
  <div id="ls-anc-info"></div>
</div>
```